# Antialiasing disappears when using EffectComposer in Three JS

Tags: three.js

When I apply any Pass to EffectComposer http://prntscr.com/u0io3g I get teeth on the edges, when without extra passes everything is smoothed out http://prntscr.com/u0ipbt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default anti-aliasing of WebGL does only work if you directly render to screen (or the default framebuffer). When using `EffectComposer`, you have two options:

- Apply an FXAA pass at the end of your pass chain.
- Create the `EffectComposer` with instances of `THREE.WebGLMultisampleRenderTarget` (does not work with WebGL 1).

Below are two examples that demonstrate the usage of FXAA and multisampled render targets with `three.js`.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_fxaa.html
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl2_multisampled_renderbuffers